# ¿Cómo hacer esta suma entre dos fechas en SQL?

Tags: sql, sum

tengo un problema, necesito crear una suma del total debe estar entre la fecha y hace 11 meses, esto para cada ID, la tabla original es Fecha,id,total

Este es el ejemplo de lo que quiero, teniendo de regreso fecha,id,resultado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

lo único que tengo en este momento es retroceder 11 meses desde cada fecha

```
SELECT FECHA,ID,sum(case when FECHA between FECHA and date_sub(FECHA, INTERVAL 11 MONTH)then TOTAL end) as RESULTADO 
from TABLE1 
group by FECHA,ID
```

**(trabajo en bigquery)**

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! si queres agrupar por id, porque pones la fecha? eso no deberia ir en el where directamente?

Comment: ya lo hice de esa manera y no me arroja el resultado, ahora debo tener ambas columnas fecha y id

Comment: entonces, que va en cada columna?

Comment: la tabla original esta fecha, id, piezas. en el resultado de estar  fecha ,id y resultado. ejemplo si es fecha febrero 2021 id=3 entonces debe hacerme la sumatoria del total desde la fecha febrero 2021 a marzo 2020 teniendo una tabla final de fecha febrero 2021 id=3 y sumatoria de los 11 meses

Comment: Me sorprende que haya dos respuestas sin que Fernanda haya explicado en qué motor de BD trabaja.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deberías etiquetar la base de datos que estás utilzando, asumo que es MySql.

Para obtener la suma por ID debes agrupar solo por el ID.

En la clausula WHERE puedes filtrar solo los registros desde hace 11 meses a la fecha actual.

```
SELECT ID, sum(TOTAL) AS RESULTADO
FROM TABLE1
WHERE FECHA BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 11 MONTH) AND CURDATE()
GROUP BY ID
ORDER BY ID;
```

Esta query para cada ID y FECHA suma el total para ese ID y las fechas de los últimos 11 meses:

```
SELECT t1.ID, t1.FECHA, sum(t2.TOTAL) AS RESULTADO
FROM TABLE1 t1
INNER JOIN TABLE1 t2 ON t1.ID = t2.ID AND t2.FECHA BETWEEN DATE_SUB(t1.FECHA, INTERVAL 11 MONTH) AND t1.FECHA
GROUP BY t1.ID, t1.FECHA
ORDER BY t1.ID, t1.FECHA;
```

Comment: No es lo que yo quiero porque el resultado debe estar la  la fecha,id y resultado, por otro lado curdate no me sirve porque estamos hablando de la fecha actual, de la cual si yo quiero saber la sumatoria de febrero 2021 debe ser la sumatoria de febrero 2021 a marzo 2020

Comment: Es que si agrupas por ID, ¿que fecha querés mostrar? la mayor, la menor....? (Tene en cuenta que para cada ID le pueden corresponder varias fechas como se muestra en tu imagen). Para usar otra fecha distinta de la actual reemplaza CURDATE() por la fecha que quieras usar.

Comment: Si es sumatoria de marzo 2021 a febrero 2020 debe aparecer marzo 2021 id y la sumatoria, en cuanto a lo que comentas cambiar el curdate, no es viable cambiarlo ya que es estático debo hacer esa operación por 15 años por 12 meses serian 180 querys para eso, la cual a mi me consume recursos eso

Comment: A entonces tu quieres para cada ID y para cada FECHA que sume el total de los últimos 11 meses (de ese ahí y esa fecha), eso es correcto?

Comment: es correcto!!!!

Comment: Ahí agregué una segunda query, no había entendido bien que necesitabas.

Comment: la sumatoria me la da al  reves es decir  fecha es 2020  me hace la sumatoria para el 2021 no para el 2019

Comment: Puse al revés la condición en el ON, `t2.FECHA BETWEEN DATE_SUB(t1.FECHA, INTERVAL 11 MONTH) AND t1.FECHA`, voy a corregir la query.

Answer (score 0):

Estoy tratando de simular tú escenario agregando cuatro registros a la tabla.

Si puedes observar en el siguiente código, en el WHERE obtengo rango de fechas restando los 11 meses a la variable @fecha con la función [DATEADD](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dateadd-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

```
DECLARE @TABLE TABLE (fecha smalldatetime,DataId int,Total float)
INSERT INTO @TABLE (fecha,DataId,Total) VALUES ('01/03/2021',3,10),('01/03/2021',3,10),('01/01/2021',3,20),('01/01/2021',3,30)
DECLARE @FECHA smalldatetime='19/05/2021'

SELECT t.DataId, SUM(total) as total FROM @TABLE t where
 t.fecha BETWEEN  DATEADD(MM, -11, @FECHA) AND @FECHA
GROUP BY fecha,DataId
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]